# How many roots are there modulo 7?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> How many roots does the polynomial $$(x^3+2x+2)^7-(x^3+2x-5)\in \mathbb{Z}_7[x] $$ have in $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Do we have to reduce the polynomial modulo 7 using fermat theorem and then calculate the roots?

If I have that correctly the polynomial is equivalent to $2x-5$ in modulo 7.

Is that correct?

Comment: For every element $a\in\Bbb{Z}_7$ we have $(a^3+2a+2)^7=a^3+2a+2$ by Little Fermat. This is way more efficient here than reducing the polynomial modulo $7$ which would begin (by Freshman's dream)
$$(x^3+2x+2)^7=(x^3)^7+(2x)^7+2^7=x^{21}+2x^7+2\ldots$$

Comment: Ag so we get 0,and there are no roots? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Mary Star, the polynomial is not zero. But its values at the points in $\Bbb{Z}_7$ all are. It's a degree 21 polynomial so it has 21 zeros in an algebraic closure. Luckily you were only asked to count the zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_7$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Wouldn’t there be some repeated roots in the base field?  I think $x^3 + 2x + 2 = (x-2)^2 (x+4)$ mod $7$.

Comment: Absolutely, @ErickWong! I mentally checked the derivative, but made a sign error. The $21$ zeros in the closure need to be counted with multiplicities.

Comment: The derivative $-(3x^2+2)$ also vanishes at $x=5$, so that is another double root of the degree 21 polynomial. (In case anyone is wondering I mentally checked that $3x^2=2$ has no solutions in $\Bbb{Z}_7$. Silly, yes :-)

Comment: @MaryStar can't you just plug in all the elemnts of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and see if they are roots of your polynomial? I know it is pretty tedious, but for finite fields this is a viable strategy

Answer (score 1):

Since $$(x^3+2x+2)\equiv_7 (x^3+2x-5)$$ we have $$y^7\equiv_7 y$$

where $y= x^3+2x+2$. But this is true for any $y$ by Fermat little theorem, so the answer is 7.